Square-root of locally integrable functions
Suppose I am given an $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d)$ function $f(x,y)$. It then defines an inner product on the space of test-functions $\mathcal{D}$, via
$$
\mathcal{E}(\phi,\psi)=\int (1+f(x,y))\phi(x)\psi(y)\mathrm{d} x \mathrm{d}y\, .
$$
When can you take the square-root of $1+f(x,y)$, in the sense that there exists $\sqrt{F}\colon\mathcal{D}\to L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with
$$
\mathcal{E}(\phi,\phi)=\int (\sqrt{F}\phi)(x)^2\mathrm{d}x\, .
$$
If we were dealing with finite vectors instead, this is the same as asking for the square-root of a matrix. If we were on $L^2$, the argument is similar, because we could use the spectral theorem. But it seems in general hard to find the class of all $f$ for which this is possible.

It would be helpful if you add your approach for both the finite dimensional and $L^2$ cases.

@EstebanG.Sure! Using the spectral theorem, you can take square roots of operators. Another method is to use the power series expansion. You can take $1+f(x,y)$ as a convolution operator and then apply said methods.
